# What is the correct way to map and translate cookies in logstash?

Tags: logstash

My input is a log from IIS server with cookies included. I want my output (elasticsearch) to have a field like this:

```
"cookies": {
  "cookie_name": "cookie_value"
}
```

Also for some cookies I want their values to be replaced with some other values from a dictionary.

Basically, I think the following filter config solves my problem:

```
kv {
    source => "cookie"
    target => "cookies"
    trim => ";"
    include_keys => [ "cookie_name1","cookie_name2" ]
}
translate {
    field => "cookies.cookie_name1"
    destination => "cookies.cookie_name1"
    dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/dict.yaml"
    override => "true"
    fallback => "%{cookies.cookie_name1}"
}
```

The problem is that I don't know if it’s the right way to do this, and whether it will work at all (especially the `cookies.cookie_name` part).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
kv {
    source => "cookie"
    target => "cookies"
    field_split => ";+"
    include_keys => [ "cookie_name1","cookie_name2" ]
}
translate {
    field => "[cookies][cookie_name1]"
    destination => "[cookies][cookie_name1]"
    dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/dict.yaml"
    override => "true"
    fallback => "%{[cookies][cookie_name1]}"
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/plugins-filters-kv.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/plugins-filters-translate.html